# How to display several points of a KML with the same coordinates in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, kml

I've got a KML, where several points have the same coordinate, similar to following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>test.kml</name>
    <visibility>0</visibility>
    <open>1</open>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Place 1</name>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>7.0901548880586,50.723973666434,0</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Place 2</name>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>7.0901548880586,50.723973666434,0</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

If I click on the POI in an OpenLayers-map, only the last point can be selected. Google Maps' solution to the problem are `next`- and `previous`-buttons, in Google Earth the placemark "splits" into two (or more) placemarks so you can select one of the placemarks.
Is it possible to create a similar behaviour in OpenLayers?

There is an analog problem if there are two KMLs with placemarks with the same coordinate. I need a solution for this problem, too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>test1.kml</name>
    <visibility>0</visibility>
    <open>1</open>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Place 1</name>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>7.0901548880586,50.723973666434,0</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>test2.kml</name>
    <visibility>0</visibility>
    <open>1</open>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Place 2</name>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>7.0901548880586,50.723973666434,0</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tyr to use `Strategy.Cluster`: see http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster.html

Add option: `threshold: 2` at Cluster creation, this allows you to view element that does not overlap, and set `distance` (in pixels) see http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/strategy-cluster-threshold.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was able to successfully implement your solution for the case of multiple points in one KML, but now there is a small square instead of my marker. Is it possible to change the marker for the cluster?
How can I adapt the solution for the similar problem with two KMLs with POIs with the same coordinates?

Comment: Okay, I solved the marker-problem with the help of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641919/openlayers-nice-marker-clustering , but still need help for the problem with the POIs of two layers sharing one coordinate.

Comment: The only thing I can think is to display it in a single layer oops! Want to highlight or select the features?

Comment: I want to select one point and display its description in a balloon. In the case of a cluster there should be a choice, which of the clustered points should be selected.

Comment: See this example: http://jorix.github.com/OL-FeaturePopups/examples/feature-popups.html uses a control written by me that you can help.

Comment: Your FeaturePopup-Code is great and helps me a lot! Thank you!

Comment: Okay, now I've got one more question:

Comment: Is it possible to use the style, which I extracted from the KML, for the clustered POIs, and add a label to it, which counts the number of POIs at the place of the map? By now I created an own StyleMap, where I defined the externalGraphic and a label, which counts the POIs at one place, and ignore the style of the KML. If I don't do so I get the small squares as marker for the clusters. But maybe I'll add a KML, where I don't know the url of the marker, so I get problems to define the externalGraphic.

Comment: Use both! (extractStyles:true & StyleMap for clusters) The KML format+extractStyles:true creates features with style, but cluster strategy creates features without style. See eg https://gist.github.com/jorix/6c74f35a5700e194ebd7 (used in production with KLM+extractStyles:true)

Comment: But I want to give the cluster the same marker. How can I allocate the same marker as the one for the other points, e.g. if I don't know the url of the marker?

Comment: But then you should avoid clustering features with different icon, but may be in the same location, so ... The `context` allows you to view all the features of the cluster (see array  `feature.cluster` each item of them have a style (from KML) get by `feature.cluster[i].attributes.styleUrl` and `feature.cluster[i].style ...`) .

Comment: `feature.cluster[0].style.externalGraphic` was the right hint. When I'll cluster features with different icons I'll a) use circles as proposed by you, b) the icon of the most important feature (like http://openflights.org/blog/2009/10/21/customized-openlayers-cluster-strategies/ ) or c) the icon, which represent the most features of the cluster.

Once again many thanks for your help! When I'll ever get >15 reputation I'll +1 your comments! You provided great answers to my (newbie-) questions!

Comment: I'm glad it was useful. Not so newbie ;-) this is a complex issue come to assimilate many concepts.